# Need for troubleshooting in UNIX w/ shell script program and IF..THEN command

Tags: unix, shell, sqlplus

Since you guys are having lots of questions or not enough info to work with, below is proprietary information and as such be careful as you can. The question  – (please refer to if [$7 -eq "AAA"]...then statement - in bold ) has a problem with an output, where I can only output/print count of  'AAA' regardless the variable coming in either 'BBB' or ‘AAA’. As a result, and as an error, the program outputs/prints count of ‘AAA’.

Again, in this situation I tried with my best knowledge to explain to those available and savvy.  Thanks.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Print the run date
echo "**********************"
echo " TALK Program "
echo " Run Date " 
     date
echo "**********************"

#            DIRECTORIES/VARIABLES/PARAMETERS

p1=$1
p2=$2
p3=$3
p4=$4
p5=$5
p6=$6
p7=$7
p8=$8

echo "***********************************************"
echo "The parameteres are"
echo "                                  "
echo "  Param 1 (Username/Password)   = "
echo "  Param 2 (User account number) = "$2
echo "  Param 3 (Requestor name)      = "$3
echo "  Param 4 (Requestor ID)        = "$4
echo "  Param 7 (AAA or BBB)          = "$7
echo "  Param 8 (TALK Data Filename)  = "$8
echo "***********************************************"

AREA1=$WILLS_TOP/bin                      # Switch-variable points to GENEX bin dir
AREA2=$WILLS_TOP/sql                      # Switch-variable points to GENEX sql dir

SQL_CTL=$AREA1/WILLSTALK.ctl              # Name of SQL*Load ctrl file                  
SQL_VALID=$AREA2/WILLSTALK.sql            # Name of validation PL/SQL script

FTP_BIN=/usr/local/bin                    # Where ftp program is
UNIX_GET=$FTP_BIN/ftpmget.sh              # Name of UNIX file get program
UNIX_PUT=$FTP_BIN/ftpmput.sh              # Name of UNIX file put program
UNIX_DEL=$FTP_BIN/ftpdel.sh               # Name of UNIX file delete program 

TEMP=/tmp                                 # Name of temp dir

INPUT_DIR=/oracle/inbound                 # For DVLP  Where input file is comming from
ARCHIVE_NT_DIR=/oracle/inbound/RFS_DVLP   # For DVLP  Modified on 2005

OUTPUT_DIR=/oracle/outbound/              # Where output file is going to
OUTPUT_UNIX_DIR=$OUTCSF/$$OUTLOG/         # Directory of where output is
DES_NAME=${OUTPUT_UNIX_DIR}${OUT_FILE}    # Where output is going to be

USERACCNUM=$p2                            # User Account Number
USERNAME=$p5                              # Username
PASSWORD=$p6                              # Password
AAA_OR_BBB=$p7                            # Either 'AAA' or default of 'BBB'
DATAFILE_NAME=$p8                         # Datafile name (NT)  
SERVER='172.........'                     # Server (NT)
LOG_DIR=$WILLS_TIP/log                    # Path of log dir
LOCAL_DIR=$WILLS_TIP/data                 # Directory where file is at (UNIX)
ARCHIVE_DIR=$WILLS_TIP/archive            # Directory for archive (UNIX)
FILE_NAME=""                              # File name (UNIX)
FILE_TRAN_TYPE='ascii'                    # File transfer type

#*****************************************************************************
#                               MAIN PROCEDURE
#*****************************************************************************
if [ ! "$p7" ]
then
     echo "At least one MS Excel Update Data File must be entered !"
     echo "No files were entered."
     exit 1
fi

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#  Remove all MS Excel datafile in $GENEX_TOP/data directory if exist
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
rm -f $WILLS_TIP/data/TALK* 

#--------
#  FTP
#--------
${UNIX_GET} $p5 $p6 $SERVER $INPUT_DIR $DATAFILE_NAME $LOCAL_DIR "" $TEMP $FILE_TRAN_TYPE 

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
    echo "The MS Excel Datafile(s) ftp has failed."
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -s $LOCAL_DIR/$p8 ]
then
    echo "FTP command executed, but MS Excel file(s) did not get copied."
    exit 2
fi

#-----------------------------------------
# SQL*Loads - New MS Excel file to load
#-----------------------------------------

for i in $LOCAL_DIR/$DATAFILE_NAME   
do
   SQLOAD_DAT_FILE=`echo $i | sed "s/\// /g" | awk ' { print $NF } '`

   SQLOAD_LOG_FILE=$SQLOAD_DAT_FILE.log         # Sqlload log file name
   SQLOAD_BAD_FILE=$SQLOAD_DAT_FILE.bad         # Sqlload bad file name

   if [ -s $LOG_DIR/$SQLOAD_BAD_FILE ]
   then
       rm -f $LOG_DIR/$SQLOAD_BAD_FILE  # Remove prev. bad file, if such exists
       echo "Previous bad file has been successfully removed."
   else
       echo "No bad file was identified and removed."
       echo "Resume Normal Processing."
   fi

   echo $i
   echo "Now loading datafile:  $LOCAL_DIR/$SQLOAD_DAT_FILE"

   #---------------------------------------------------------------
   sed "s/@USERACCNUM/$USERACCNUM/" $SQL_CTL > $TEMP/WILLSTAL.ctl  # Changing '@USERACCNUM' 
   #--------------------------------------------------------------- 

   sqlldr userid=${p1} control=$TEMP/WILLSTALK.ctl \
             log=$LOG_DIR/$SQLOAD_LOG_FILE \
             bad=$LOG_DIR/$SQLOAD_BAD_FILE \
            data=$LOCAL_DIR/$SQLOAD_DAT_FILE

   if test ! -s $LOG_DIR/$SQLOAD_BAD_FILE
   then
        tail -20 $LOG_DIR/$SQLOAD_LOG_FILE
        echo "*** Done SQL*Loader Script ***"
   else
        echo "The SQL*Load for MS Excel Update file has FAILED due to BAD DATA."
        echo "*** Exitting Script On Failure ***"
        echo "*** Process is ready for NEXT LOAD! ***" 
        exit 1
   fi
done

#----------------------------------------
#       To run a PL/SQL script
#----------------------------------------
sqlplus -s $p1 @$SQL_VALID $AAA_OR_BBB
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "The PL/SQL script for validation has FAILED."
    exit 1
fi

#---------------------------------------------------------- 
# Now run SQL*Plus script Flat File Report After Updating 
#----------------------------------------------------------

sqlplus -s $1 <<EOF

set echo off
set heading off
set space 0
set newpage 0
set pagesize 0
set feed off
set term on

SPOOL $OUTCSF/$OUTLOG/l$4.log

SELECT 'spool $OUTCSF/$APPLOUT/o$4.out' FROM dual;

SPOOL OFF

@$OUTCSF/$OUTLOG/l$4.log

Select 'Run Date: '||to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY') From dual;

Select '*************************************************************' From dual; 

SELECT 'ERRORS Found: '||count(*) 
  FROM gnx_rel_date_temp   
 WHERE error_text IS NOT NULL;

Select '--------------- ----------- ---------------------------------' From dual;
Select 'TRX NUMBER      NEW DATE                           ERROR TEXT' From dual;
Select '--------------- ----------- ---------------------------------' From dual;
SELECT trx_num||'|'||new_date||'|'||error_text
  FROM will_rel_date_temp   
 WHERE error_text IS NOT NULL;

Select '*************************************************************' From dual;

#-------------
#---- AAA ----
#-------------
if [ $7 -eq "AAA" ] then
   SELECT 'Total AAA Updated: '||count(*)||' records'         
     FROM reldatetemp             
         ,allcustomers     
    WHERE trx_num = trx_no       
      AND error_text IS NULL       
      AND attr2 IS NOT NULL          
      AND attr2 = TO_CHAR(new_date,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');  
else
    exit 0
fi
#---------------
#---- BBB ----
#---------------
if [ $7 -eq "BBB" ] then
   SELECT 'Total BBB Updated: '||count(*)||' records'         
     FROM reldatetemp             
         ,allcustomers     
    WHERE trx_num = trx_no       
      AND error_text IS NULL       
      AND attr1 IS NOT NULL          
      AND attr1 = TO_CHAR(new_date,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');  
else 
    exit 0
fi

SPOOL OFF
EOF

#----------------------------------------------
#   To delete the data files on NT
#----------------------------------------------
${UNIX_DEL} $p5 $p6 $SERVER $INPUT_DIR $DATAFILE_NAME $TEMP

mv $WILLS_TIP/data/$DATAFILE_NAME $WILLS_TIP/archive/. 

#  All Done!
echo "*** End of program *** "
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything between "sqlplus -s $1 << EOF" and "EOF" is called "here-doc" and intended for consumption by sqlplus. You can't really expect sqlplus to understand shell scripting in the form of "if [ "$7" -eq ....] ".

You should make all "ifs" outside of the here-doc and use results in it. Like this:

```
if [ "$7" -eq "AAA" ] ; then
  attr="attr2"
elsif [ "$7" -eq "BBB" ] ; then
  attr="attr1"
else
  echo "Bogus $7 - need AAA or BBB"
fi

....

sqlplus -s $1 <<EOF
...
SELECT 'Total $7 Updated: '||count(*)||' records'         
 FROM reldatetemp             
     ,allcustomers     
WHERE trx_num = trx_no       
  AND error_text IS NULL       
  AND ${attr} IS NOT NULL          
  AND ${attr} = TO_CHAR(new_date,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');
...
EOF
```

Pay attention to "${attr}" and read a decent tutorial on shell scripting.

Answer (score 0):

How can the script possibly continue after this code:

```
#-------------
#---- AAA ----
#-------------
if [ $7 -eq "AAA" ] then
   SELECT 'Total AAA Updated: '||count(*)||' records'         
     FROM reldatetemp             
         ,allcustomers     
    WHERE trx_num = trx_no       
      AND error_text IS NULL       
      AND attr2 IS NOT NULL          
      AND attr2 = TO_CHAR(new_date,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS');  
else
    exit 0
fi
```

If $7 = "AAA" then run the select, if $7 is not = "AAA" exit the script.....

Regards
K

Comment: This part is inside here-doc, so "if" would not be evaluated